# Recursive descent parser in C

Tags: c

I have the following production rule

```
E -> (EX)|Y

X -> vE|^E|>E

Y -> -E|p|q|r
```

and I have the following code

```
int i;
int j;
int count;
char l;

void match(char t);
void E();
void X();
void Y();

void match(char t) 
{ 
    if (l == t) { 
        count += 1;
    } 
    else{
        printf("Error"); 
    }
} 

void E()
{
    if(l == '('){
        match('(');
        E();
        X();
        if(l == ')'){
            match(')');
            return;
        }
    }
    else{
        Y();
    }
    return;
}

void Y()
{
    if(l == '-'){
        match('-');
        E();
    }
    else if(l == 'p'){
        match('p');
        return;
    }
    else if(l == 'q'){
        match('q');
        return;
    }
    else if(l == 'r'){
        match('r');
        return;
    }
}

void X()
{
    if(l == 'v'){
        match('v');
        E();
    }
    else if(l == '^'){
        match('^');
        E();
    }
    else if(l == '>'){
        match('>');
        E();
    }
    return;
}

int parse(char* g){
  count = 0;
  //int k = strlen(g);
  l = g[count];
  //sprintf("%c",l);
  E();
  if(l == '$'){
    printf("Parsing successful");
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    printf("Parsing unsuccessful");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

which doesnt seem to work. The program crashes without printing anything. What is the problem in the code? The code runs inititally but nothing happens and then the program just exits. I dont think there is a segmentation fault but could someone please advise and help

Comment: It looks weird that `l` is not updated during the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Your code never updates `l`. If I understand your code correctly, you’d want to update `l` in `match` at the very least:

```c
void match(char t) 
{ 
    if (l == t) { 
        count += 1;
        l = g[count];
    } 
    else {
        printf("Error"); 
    }
}
```

For this to work you need to make `g` global` (or, ideally, you’d *remove* all global variables and encapsulate the state of your parser into a structure that you pass through to your parsing functions).